# send location updates to server from web app

Tags: web-services, html

I have written a web app with a few JSP pages and Java servlets running on a Tomcat server. The app needs to be able to send location updates to one of the Servlets every x seconds. I have found the html5 watchPosition(sucess_callback, error_callback) function to get the location updates from the web page. I'm thinking.. once I get the update from this function.. I'll put code in the callback function to send the update to a Servlet. But adding the watchPosition function to every JSP page in the app seems cumbersome. What is the right way to send periodic GPS updates to the server no matter whatever webpage the user is viewing in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can create any code which continues to send location data when the user loads another web-page. The web is a stateless thing and when the user opens another page other code is executed. I suspect that the JSP is the codebase from which HTML is produced when sent to the mobile-phone. My idea would be to add the location sending functionality as AJAX requests in the Javascript. If your web-app is based on many links between pages and full loads it could also be an idea to implement Ajax for loading new content into the page.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply. So, do I have to add the AJAX code in all of the web pages?